# Convert SQL Syntax from MySQL 5.0 to Oracle 12c

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am trying to migrated MySQL 5.0 views to Oracle 12c.  This is the syntax I have in MySQL:

```
select count(`table1`.`uuid`) AS `Count`,
`table2`.`description` AS `STATUS`,
`table3`.`name` AS `Court` 
from ((`table2` join `table1`) 
join `table3`) 
where ((`table1`.`statusCode` = `table2`.`code`) 
and (`table3`.`uuid` = `table1`.`courtUuid`)) 
group by `table1`.`courtUuid`,`table2`.`description`;
```

This is the syntax I have for Oracle 12c:

```
select count(table1.uuid) AS Count,
table2.description AS STATUS,
table3.NAME as Court
from table2
join table1
on (table1.statuscode = table2.code)
join table3
on (table3.uuid = table1.courtuuid)
group by table1.courtuuid,table2.description;
```

When I run the Oracle 12c syntax, I get:

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 1

However, if I add table3.NAME as part of the group by, I get 866 rows.  The query in MySQL produces 1025 rows.

```
select count(table1.uuid) AS Count,
table2.description AS STATUS,
table3.NAME as Court
from table2
join table1
on (table1.statuscode = table2.code)
join table3
on (table3.uuid = table1.courtuuid)
group by table1.courtuuid,table2.description,table3.NAME;
```

Can someone help me figure this one out?

Comment: 1st sql doesn't seem totally equal with the 2nd one from the point of view of paranthesis ... Could you try exactly the same sql ( 1st one ) for Oracle DB ?

Comment: Can you please come up with some sample data that you can run the MySQL queries and Oracle queries on and the results that both databases return?

Comment: Note that your oracle code will run in mysql. You can test for differences in the data by running the sane code on both instances. Also, you could add the extra field to the original mysql code. I'm pretty convinced it's at least partially a difference in the data.

Comment: @MatBailie: Adding the extra field to the first query given by Gordon Linoff gives the same result in MySQL. This new query, along with the first query given by Gordon Linoff as he provided it, give both the same result in Oracle, 866 rows, and in MySQL, 1025 rows.  This is the same result in MySQL as the original query in MySQL.  I am going to inform the developers and business analysts at my place of work about these findings.  Thanks!

Comment: The answer to my question is the first query provided by Gordon Linoff. Another alternative is the first query provided by Gordon LInoff with the addition of the extra field in the GROUP BY clause as indicated by MatBailie. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
select count(table1.uuid) AS Count,
       table2.description AS STATUS,
       table3.NAME as Court
from table2 join
     table1
     on table1.statuscode = table2.code join
     table3
     on (able3.uuid = table1.courtuuid
group by table3.name, table2.description;
```

The unaggregated columns in the `select` should be in the `group by`.  Unfortunately, MySQL has a (mis)feature that does not require this logic.

Strictly speaking, you could also do:

```
select count(table1.uuid) AS Count,
       table2.description AS STATUS,
       max(table3.NAME) as Court
from table2 join
     table1
     on table1.statuscode = table2.code join
     table3
     on table3.uuid = table1.courtuuid
group by table1.courtuuid, table2.description;
```

This is more equivalent to your query, but the first version is probably what you intend.

Comment: If the mysql query generated 1025 rows, but the oracle query only generated 866 rows, even with an extra expression in the group by, surely there must also be a data issue? *(Adding an expression to the group by should increase the number of rows, not reduce the number of rows?)*